# LINQ expression that contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have this query:

```
var list = (from t1 in context1.SomeTable
            join t2 in context2.SomeTable on t1.ID equals t2.ID
            where //some where clause
            select new { t1.SomeField, t2.SomeField }).ToList());
```

I will get this error when this query tries to execute:

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

1. Why is this not allowed with `LINQ to Entities`?
2. Is it still possible with `LINQ to Entities` in another way?
3. What would be a work around for this?

Comment: Can you please explain in pseudo code how you would LIKE the query to be executed? What should happen on the server(s) and what should happen locally in your code?

Comment: In my case, i have just split up my tables in my DB, my systems tables in a SystemContext and the rest of my tables in Applicationcontext. So it is still on the same server, same connection, just 2 different Entity Models.

Comment: So you are putting them in two different contexts, but you are assuming that the system should realize that the contexts are the same? Do you expect the entirety of the query to run server side? If so, I assume you should have all query relevant tables included in the same context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd imagine it's because the statement you're building up is converted to SQL behind the scenes and run on the database. Because different context could come from different databases or even different servers, there's no guarantee that the data in context2 is available to context1 when the server is being queried.

You could return the data from each context and convert to IEnumerable and then perform standard linq queries then but you've got a clear overhead of data transfer and in-memory processing that would have otherwise been performed by the database engine.